# how to access UNKNOWN in sql server's boolean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, boolean, bit

Hi I learned sql server's `BIT` has true, false, and unknown. For example, the comparison `1 > NULL` yields `unknown`.

I know I can check it indirectly: if `x is null or y is null`, then the comparison `x > y` must be `unknown`.

Is there a way to access `unknown` directly? For example

```
select *
into #t
from (
    SELECT 1 as [x], 1 as [y] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as [x], 2 as [y] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as [x], NULL as [y]
) as a


SELECT *
from #t
--x y
--1 1
--1 2
--1 NULL

select *
    ,/* ???? */ as [is x > y]
from #t
--want to have:
--x y      is x > y
--1 1      0
--1 2      0
--1 NULL   unknown
```

Comment: I think "unknown" is represented as `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
select *
into #t
from (
    SELECT 1 as [x], 1 as [y] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as [x], 2 as [y] UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as [x], NULL as [y]
) as a


SELECT *
from #t
--x y
--1 1
--1 2
--1 NULL

select *,
    case  
        when x > y then '1' 
        when x is null or y is null then 'unknown'
        else '0' 
        end as [is x > y]
from #t

--x y    is x > y
--1 1    0
--1 2    0
--1 NULL unknown

-- Don't forget to delete your temp table when done. 
drop table  #t
```

Comment: Thank u @Chuck isn't the idea of temp table that u don't need to drop it?

Comment: Hi Y Zhang, I guess that it is just a best practice, see here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/522d302a-857f-4730-b49f-cca7fb236912/is-it-necessary-to-clean-up-drop-temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `CASE` expression with an `IS NULL` predicate to return the string 'unknown' as the last column value, which will also require the other '0' and '1' values as varchar literals to avoid implicit conversion of the 'unknown' string literal to int.

```
SELECT
      x
    , y
    , CASE WHEN x > y THEN '1' WHEN x <= y THEN '0' ELSE 'unknown' END AS [is x > y]
FROM #t;
```